# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Anime & Manga Stack Exchange](http://anime.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Can Pokemon aside from Meowth learn how to talk?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6383/can-pokemon-aside-from-meowth-learn-how-to-talk)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Who is the snitch in Tantei Gakuen Q?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6416/who-is-the-snitch-in-tantei-gakuen-q)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can a clone be in sync with its original user when it is still active?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6482/can-a-clone-be-in-sync-with-its-original-user-when-it-is-still-active)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why do characters always wear the same clothes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/why-do-characters-always-wear-the-same-clothes)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Did Sasuke get all of Itachi's special abilities?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6541/did-sasuke-get-all-special-abilities-of-itachi)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How come Naruto's Chakra responds to Wood Elements?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6567/how-come-narutos-chakra-respond-to-wood-elements)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6813/name-of-the-anime-where-the-girls-are-the-great-old-ones

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why does the drawing style in manga or anime often change when a character is displaying big emotions?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6556/why-does-the-drawing-style-in-manga-or-anime-often-change-when-a-character-is-di)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What effect does Kairoseki's have on Haki?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6759/what-effect-does-kairosekis-have-on-haki)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Why does Last Order state her name twice?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/why-does-last-order-state-her-name-twice)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---